# Custom listView with SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have created `ListView` fetching data from app db, and it's working fine, when I want to display just one information, like team name, in one entry.

Now I'm trying to display more information, like team name, date, and town (all data from db, delivered by Cursor). And I can't make it work, Intent is displaying ListView  but there is no text in any of the entries... I don't know how to explain it more clearly.

Intent code:

```
 public class Games extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button bNewGame;
ListView gameList;
GameDayTableAdapter db;
Cursor c;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.games);
    bNewGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNewGame);
    bNewGame.setOnClickListener(this);
    gameList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvGameList);
    db = new GameDayTableAdapter(this);
    db.open();
    c = db.getAll();
    startManagingCursor(c);
    setListView();
}

private void setListView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, c,
            new String[] { AbstractDbAdapter.TEAM_NAME, AbstractDbAdapter.GAME_DAY_HOME_GAME, AbstractDbAdapter.GAME_DAY_DATE },
            new int[] { R.id.game_entry_team, R.id.game_entry_home, R.id.game_entry_date });
    gameList.setClickable(true);
    gameList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {

        }
    });

    gameList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    gameList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bNewGame:
        Intent intent = new Intent(Games.this, NewGame.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        db.close();
        finish();
        break;
    }
}
```

game_list_entry.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/game_entry_team"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/game_entry_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/game_entry_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

That's what I managed to do based on some tutorial available on-line, but not, it's not working, and I don't know how to fix it. I found other tutorials where people create new class which extends `SimpleCursorAdapter`, but that looks like a lot of extra work, and I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting your list to use the expandablelist row view that comes with the framework.  You need to specify your custom one instead.

Replace this:

```
android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1
```

With this:

```
R.layout.game_list_entry
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, on my smartphone it's a real pain to copy code.  :p. (Yes, I'm addicted to SO.  Wanna make something of it?).